# Angularjs displaying ng-repeat results under a field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

repet to display results in a input field.

```
Here is the data (being returned from controller scope is companycodes)
company     code 
abc         111
abc         10012
abc         6434
xyz         1235
xyz         33

<div ng-repeat="x in companycodes">
<h3>{{x.company}}</h3>
<input type="text" ng-name="code"  ng-model=x.code>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is that it lists codes under company heading i.e,

```
abc
   111
   10012
   6434
xyz
   1235
   33
```

Can you please let me know how to change the ng-repeat to get the output desired. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this actually what your html looks like? You need a '>' at the end of input, and change x.Company to x.company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a filter to group the data by `company` then repeat the `code` having the corresponding `company`

JS

```
myModule.filter('groupBy', function () {
  return function (array, expression) {
    var result = [], i = 0;
    if (!angular.isArray(array)) {
      return array;
    }
    for (; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      var value = array[i][expression];
      if (result.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        result.push(value);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };
})
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="company in (companycodes | groupBy: 'company')">
  <h3>{{company}}</h3>
  <div data-ng-repeat="comp in companycodes | filter: {company: company}">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="comp.code">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bhQVDUVJS8Tz7yjaEPaM?p=preview